# How do I reduce the size of a pdf file that contains images?

Tags: pdf, compression

I have a pdf file that contains images and I want to reduce its size in order to upload it to a site with a size limit.

So, how can I reduce the size of a pdf file from the command-line?

Comment: by "images" probably you mean "raster images" but PDF files can also contain vector images, which [can be really large](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/pdf-size-is-content-stream-the-problem/m-p/2286382), and which are harder to compress, see also [Replacing vector images in a PDF with raster images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47076/replacing-vector-images-in-a-pdf-with-raster-images)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use [**`gs`**](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/gs1.html) - GhostScript (PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer) as follows:

- Set [pdfwrite](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Devices.html#pdf-writer) as output device by `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`
- Use the appropriate `-dPDFSETTINGS`.

From [Documentation](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/VectorDevices.html#controls-and-features-specific-to-postscript-and-pdf-input):

> `-dPDFSETTINGS=`*configuration*
> Presets the "distiller parameters" to one of four predefined settings:
>
> - **/screen** selects low-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Screen Optimized" setting.
> - **/ebook** selects medium-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "eBook" setting.
> - **/printer** selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" setting.
> - **/prepress** selects output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" setting.
> - **/default** selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file.

- [`-o` option](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#o-switch) to output file which also set `-dNOPAUSE` and `-dBATCH` (see [Interaction-related parameters](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#interaction-related-parameters))

---

**Example:**

```
$ du -h file.pdf 
27M file.pdf
```

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -q -o output.pdf file.pdf
```

```
$ du -h output.pdf 
900K    output.pdf
```

Here [`-q`](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#q) suppress normal startup messages, and also do the equivalent of [`-dQUIET`](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#dquiet) which suppresses routine information comments

Comment: Doesn't work for me. A searchable PDF output by `tesseract` remains completely unchanged when attempting to shrink it with this command.

Comment: We can also use `-compress jpeg -quality 50` type of workaround (additionally `-resize 75%`) with `convert` command.

Comment: Wow, finally, a solution to this problem.

Comment: If your current pdf page size is large, you might also need to shrink it down to normal A4 size with addional options `-sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFFitPage` because `/ebook` etc. only shrinks it according to page size

Answer (score 16):

```
ps2pdf input.pdf output.pdf
```

I got the answer from [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/243753) and it worked for me. It actually reduced 18.1Mb to 1.0Mb

Comment: Doesn't work for me. A searchable PDF output by `tesseract` remains completely unchanged when attempting to shrink it with this command.

Comment: This is awesomely simple if you don't care to choose all the options that GhostScript needs. The man pages say that the script accepts the same parameters as `gs`, it gives this example: `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress figure.ps proof.pdf`

Answer (score 4):

If the PDF file consists entirely of image data;

```
pdftk inputFile.pdf burst
mogrify -density 300 -format jpg -quality 20 pg_*.pdf 
convert *.jpg -auto-orient outputFile.pdf
```

The density value can match the density of the source image (eg 300 dpi), but the jpeg quality should be lower than the source image (e.g. 20).

Answer (score 2):

Following a pair of recipes derived from the answers of @freeman, @Pandya, and the comments of @CrisLuengo and @Phil294:

```
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook in.pdf out.pdf
```

in this case, the IMGs are reduced according to the size of output.

If your intention is to produce an output of a different size (Ex make a a4.pdf
from a A2 Poster) you may provide extra options:

```
ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFFitPage -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook a2poster.pdf a4out.pdf
```

See `man gs` for more options.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```bash
$ time pdftk myFile.pdf output myFile__SMALLER.pdf compress
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 16764928):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 8384512):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 11837440):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 8384512):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 33525760):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 7254016):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 34041856):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 33525760):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.

real    0m23.677s
user    0m23.142s
sys     0m0.540s
$ du myFile*.pdf
108M    myFile.pdf
74M     myFile__SMALLER.pdf
```

It is faster than `gs` but compresses upto 30% in this case for a 107.5MiB input file.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. A searchable PDF output by `tesseract` remains completely unchanged when attempting to shrink it with this command.

Comment: This only restores the regular PDF page stream compression if the file happens to be in uncompressed (textual) format. Won't do much usually.